# Oozie not cleaning up old jobs from Oozie database

Tags: hadoop, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I have the following properties set in my **oozie-site.xml** (Using **safety-valve** in Cloudera Manager)

```
oozie.services.ext - org.apache.oozie.service.PurgeService
oozie.service.PurgeService.older.than - 15
oozie.service.PurgeService.coord.older.than - 7
oozie.service.PurgeService.bundle.older.than - 7
oozie.service.PurgeService.purge.interval - 60
```

However, I still see some old jobs which are KILLED or completed as old as September 2014

To give an example,

I have a Coordinator which is currently in RUNNING state. When I use the Oozie Web Console to list the instances of that Co-ordinator i.e. Click on Co-ordinator tab and click on my co-ordinator and in the pop up I see the oldest job of all materialised workflow jobs (co-ordinator actions) of September 2014.

I assume the property responsible for cleaning this up is **oozie.service.PurgeService.older.than** which I have set to **15** days.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is for long running coordinator jobs with high frequency. all child workflows are never purged as the coord job is still running.

The solution is to (quoting from the external link),

> What you can do as a workaround, is split up your long-running
>   Coordinators.  For example, instead of making your Coordinator run for
>   years? forever?, **make it run for, say, 6 months**.  And have an
>   identical Coordinator scheduled to start exactly when that one ends. 
>   This will allow Oozie to cleanup the old child Workflows from that
>   Coordinator every 6 months.   Otherwise, you can schedule a cron job
>   to **manually delete** old jobs from the Database.  However, please be
>   careful about this.  When deleting a workflow job from the WF_JOBS
>   table, you'll also need to delete the workflow actions from the
>   WF_ACTIONS table that belong to it, as well as the coordinator action
>   from the WF_ACTIONS table that it belongs to.  If you miss something,
>   it will likely cause problems.

**References**:

- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Oozie-not-cleaning-up-old-jobs-from-Oozie-database/m-p/30692#U30692
- https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/zkWa2kDMyyo
- http://qnalist.com/questions/5404909/oozie-purging

**JIRA Link**:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1532